# Why does declaring an isolate scope block $emit events from being heard?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I'm using a directive that has a controller as a child scope and i'm trying to make them talk. It seems that when I $emit an an event from the child controller, the parent directive can only hear this event when it does not have an isolate scope declared. Why does declaring an isolate scope in my directive block $emit events from being heard?

**html**

```
<flippy data-click-toggle="true" data-mouseover-toggle="true">
    <flippy-front>
      <div ng-controller="test">
        <div class="test" ng-click="flip()">
          front
        </div>
      </div>
    </flippy-front>
    <flippy-back>
      <div ng-controller="test">
        <div class="test" ng-click="flip()">
          back
        </div>
      </div>
    </flippy-back>
</flippy>
```

**js**

```
poop = angular.module('angular-flippy', []);

poop.directive('flippy', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {},              <------- works when isolate scope not declared
    link: function($scope, $elem, $attrs) {

        var flip = function() {
                $elem.toggleClass('flipped');
            }

        $scope.$on("flipped", flip);

    }
  };
});

poop.controller('test', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.flip = function() {
      $scope.$emit("flipped");
    };
}]);
```

**codepen**:
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/xzteC

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It happens because your controllers scopes are not children scopes of your directive.

If you debug your application you will see

```
-->$rootScope (id: 002)
  -->directive scope (id: 003)
  -->first controller scope (id: 004)
  -->second controller scope (id: 005)
```

As you can see, directive scope and controllers scopes are siblings - relation parent-child needed to listen the event doesn't exist.

It works if you omit `scope:{}` because then your directive uses rootScope as its own scope, so it becomes parent of `test` controllers scopes.

Check the console logs to see this structure: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/tiGEy. (Watch `$parent` properties of objects)